# pywinauto - Getting property text

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm using `pywinauto` and I want to select text from one of the properties. However, I can't figure out how to access it.

```
import pywinauto
pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
path = r'C:\Users\me\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpnui.exe'
pwa_app.start(path)
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client', class_name='#32770')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
window.SetFocus()
window.print_control_identifiers(2)

Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client'    (L1421, T493, R1854, B690)
['Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client', 'Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility ClientDialog', 'Dialog']
child_window(title="Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client", class_name="#32770")
   | 
   | #32770 - ''    (L1441, T535, R1834, B647)
   | ['#32770', 'VPN:#32770']
   | child_window(class_name="#32770")
   | 
   | Static - 'VPN:'    (L1527, T548, R1551, B561)
   | ['Static', 'VPN:Static', 'VPN:', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   | child_window(title="VPN:", class_name="Static")
   | 
   | ComboBox - 'Brock AppDMZ VPN'    (L1527, T594, R1719, B615)
   | ['ComboBox', 'Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.ComboBox', 'VPN:ComboBox', 'ComboBox0', 'ComboBox1', 'Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.ComboBox0', 'Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.ComboBox1']
   | child_window(title="Brock AppDMZ VPN", class_name="ComboBox")
   | 
   | Edit - 'Brock AppDMZ VPN'    (L1530, T597, R1699, B612)
   | ['Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.Edit', 'Edit']
   | child_window(title="Brock AppDMZ VPN", class_name="Edit")
   | 
   | ComboBox - ''    (L1527, T594, R1719, B615)
   | ['ComboBox2', 'Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.ComboBox2']
   | child_window(class_name="ComboBox")
```

I want to access the value `"Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN"` in order to determine whether I'm connected to my VPN but the documentation on this library isn't super clear about how to do this.

Comment: And yeah, some code from SWAPY is detected. It tends to put constructions using low level function `find_windows` though `app.connect(title="...")` makes the same job in one line. SWAPY was good till pywinauto==0.5.4, but not maintained any more. :( By the way, please use `.set_focus()`, we found `SetFocus()` might be empty for default win32 backend and it's deprecated anyway. Use PEP8 complaint names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `print_control_identifiers()` is incomplete (the target text label is not listed here, there are 3 static texts on the window), but fortunately I have the same Cisco VPN client on my PC. The problem is that this "static" text is dynamic. :) There are 2 ways how to handle this situation.

1) Just create a window specification and check if this window exists:

```
connected_label = window.child_window(title="Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.", class_name="Static")

# default timeout is pywinauto.timings.Timings.window_find_timeout (5 sec.)
if connected_label.exists(timeout=10):
    pass # do whatever you want
```

2) Rely on the number of this static text and check its text every time you need the status of connection:

```
label = window.child_window(class_name="Static", found_index=1).wait('exists')

if label.window_text() == "Connected to Brock AppDMZ VPN.":
    pass # do whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label = window.child_window(class_name="Static", found_index=1).wait('exists')
print label.get_value()
```

Try this, `<element>.get_value()` hope this will get you the text required.